# Draw combine boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a boxplot like this
[image]

Which mean I want boxplot on the right side wider than the rest of the boxplots
I am using this code to make it, but I am not able to make the B part of the example plot.
I also want to make them wider, as shown in the B part of the example figure.

```
ggplot(dff, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Specie)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", col="red")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#FFC7CE','#FFEB9C','#C6EFCF'))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,linetype = 1)+ theme_bw()+
  geom_text(data = df1, aes(y = up+0.02, label = label), fontface="italic", 
            size=2.5, position = position_dodge(width = .75), hjust=0.4, col="blue")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black", family = "serif"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.5, 1.05), legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9, face="italic", colour = "black")) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1),sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))) + 
  labs(title = "",subtitle = "",y = y, x = "")+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept= 7.5, colour="black",linetype="dashed")+
  geom_vline(xintercept= 12.5, colour="black",linetype="solid")+
  annotate(geom="text", x=1.1, y=1.02, label="Gas exchange",family="serif",
           fontface="bold",size=3.5)+
  annotate(geom="text", x=8.2, y=1.02, label="Photochemistry",family="serif",
           fontface="bold",size=3.5)
```

[image]

Comment: maybe you could produce separate plots and combine with a cowplot package

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I was not able to reduce the gap between the two plots. is ot possible to reduce the gap to this level?

Comment: Yes, [it is possible to reduce the gap between the two plots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70218158/903061)

Comment: @GregorThomas Is there any guide to learning to control the widths? I am trying to combine two graphs, but due to widths, the second graph has become too small.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73453194/903061

Comment: I need to attach the two graphs; the thing that I am not able to understand is about widths. the link you provide, I already checked it.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset is available here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EFPcgLypZ7iexiSEE2TCFoqo-55HR8CS/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=116244076554440087729&rtpof=true&sd=true
To mutate the data

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(df, id="Specie")
head(df)
```

I am using these codes to make plots

```
pl1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=Specie)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", col="darkred")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#FFC7CE','#FFEB9C','#C6EFCF'))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,linetype = 1)+ theme_bw()+
  geom_text(data = df1, aes(y = up+0.02, label = label), fontface="italic", 
            size=2.5, position = position_dodge(width = .75), hjust=0.4, col="blue")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black", family = "serif"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.title =element_text(vjust = -6, size = 12,face="bold", family = "serif"),
        legend.position = c(0.5, 1.05), legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9, face="italic", colour = "black"))+ 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,l8,l9,l10,l11,l12)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1)#, sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))
                     )+ 
  labs(title = "A.",subtitle = "",y = y, x = "")+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept= 7.5, colour="black",linetype="dashed")+
  annotate(geom="text", x=1, y=1.02, label="Gas exchange",family="serif",
           fontface="bold",size=3.5)+
  annotate(geom="text", x=8.2, y=1.02, label="Photochemistry",family="serif",
           fontface="bold",size=3.5)
```

Plot2

```
pl2<- ggplot(data, aes(x=Specie, y=phy, fill=Specie)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", col="red")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#FFC7CE','#FFEB9C','#C6EFCF'))+
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA,linetype = 1)+ theme_bw()+
  geom_signif(color="blue", comparisons = list(c("S. chacoense","S. commersonii")),map_signif_level = T, 
              tip_length = c(0.03,0.12),textsize = 6, y_position = c(0.51),vjust=0.5)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, colour = "black", family = "serif"),
        axis.text.y.left = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y.left = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(vjust = -6, size = 12,face="bold", family = "serif"),
        legend.position = "none")+ 
  expand_limits(y=c(0,0.6))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1))) + 
  labs(title = "B.",subtitle = "",y = "", x = "")
```

For combining graphs

```
pl1 + pl2+ plot_layout(nrow = 1, widths = c(1.5,-0.1,0.5))
```

and I am getting this result
[image]